# Proof of Andrica when Assuming Oppermann

Tags: number-theory, proof-verification, conjectures, experimental-mathematics

Proof of [Andrica's conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrica%27s_conjecture) by assuming [Oppermann's conjecture.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oppermann%27s_conjecture)

Oppermann's conjecture:
$$n\geq2\wedge\pi\left(n^{2}-n\right) < \pi\left(n^{2}\right) < \pi\left(n^{2}+n\right).$$

Andrica's conjecture:
$$i\geq2\wedge\sqrt{p_{i+1}}-\sqrt{p_{i}}<1.$$
[Insert Gottfried Helms' nice proof here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1099968/28555)$\ \ \Box$

Comment: I don't know why @daniel s answer was deleted? My "hmm" was just a keyboard-reflex, that I was thinking... Just - I would have had expanded the answer by including, that by the truth of the square-root-inequality for $n \ge 1$ the OP's question was completely resolved.

Comment: @GottfriedHelms: Sorry, I told with OP that I would help him with presentation and then delete the answer as it was not really an answer. Thank you for the explanation which is what I finally decided you meant. I think OP is still thinking about changes in the form of the question but for sure must include your suggested expansion. Yes the truth of the inequality I think does it.

Comment: I have now one concern. Oppermann's conjecture focuses on the interval ***around a square-number $n^2$ .*** So this conjectures only for the case, that the center $m=n^2$ of the interval [$m-\sqrt m$ .. $m+\sqrt m$] is a square. But what if Oppermann is true for such cases, but untrue for cases, where the center $m$ is not a square-number? (I don't know actually whether this is possibly a non-issue, didn't step into the conceptual part of question too deeply)

Comment: @daniel: not necessarily. Consider there is a modular argument which tells us that between $m=n^2$ and $m-\sqrt m  = n^2-n $ there is a prime, but that this does not need to hold if $m$ not a square. Then by Andrica, we need a smaller range than $m+\sqrt m$ for the next prime to occur. But, well, I've definitely not yet stepped into this sufficiently deep...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*[update]: Upps, I see that while I'm just writing @Dan has undeleted his earlier answer. So priority (and thus also the bounty) is at Dan's, of course*

---

**I)** Let's look at some examples due to Oppermann's consideration:
$$ \small \begin{array}{}  m_{13}=13^2=169 & a_{13} = 169-13+1=157 & b_{13}=169+13-1 = 181 \\
  m_{14}=14^2=196 & a_{14} = 196-14+1=183 & b_{14}=196+14-1 = 209 \\
  m_{15}=15^2=225 & a_{15} = 225-15+1=211 & b_{15}=225+15-1 = 239 \\ 
\end{array}$$
or , written more compactly
$$ \small \begin{array}{} 
  m_{13}: &   157...168 & 169 &170... 181 \\
  m_{14}: & 183...195 & 196 & 197... 209 \\
  m_{15}: & 211...224 & 225 & 226...239 \\ 
\end{array}$$
We can see that the intervals for consecutive $m_k$ cover the integers except the numbers $n^2$, $n^2+n$ etc, which by definition are not prime.
Oppermann's conjecture is true, if in each of the intervals is at least one prime.

**II)** But because the intervals follow each other immediately, we can also look at the two intervals ***between the two consecutive squares*** $n^2$ and $(n+1)^2$.

$$ \small \begin{array} {rrrrr}
 n^2 &  \big[(n^2+1) \cdots (n^2+n-1)\big]  & (n^2+n) & \big[(n^2+n+1) \cdots ((n+1)^2-1) \big] & (n+1)^2 \\
\end{array}$$

The endpoints $n^2$ , $(n+1)^2$ and the center $n^2+n = (n+1)^2-(n+1)$ are not prime by construction, so the maximal distance between two primes can - assuming Oppermann - at most be $((n+1)^2-1) - (n^2+1)$.

**III)** Now express the inner neighbours of the two endpoints as $p_0 = n^2+1$ and $p_1=(n+1)^2-1$ which mark the greatest possible distance between two numbers in that interval , then we can refer to the Andrica-formulation $\sqrt{p_1} - \sqrt{p_0}<1$ as
$$ \sqrt{((n+1)^2-1)} - \sqrt{(n^2+1)}\lt 1$$
But this is with a small $\small 0 \le \delta \lt 1$ and thus $\small \sqrt{n^2+1} \sim n+\delta $ and $ \small \sqrt{(n+1)^2-1} \sim (n+1)-\delta $
$$ \big((n+1)-\delta \big)  - \big(n +\delta \big) = 1 - 2 \delta \lt 1$$
and thus always (for $n$ greater than some small value, perhaps even if greater than 1) true.

**IV)** From this follows, that Oppermann's conjecture implies Andrica's conjecture

Comment: Am keeping my non-answer Wikified so please accept the bounty if OP is disposed to give it.

Comment: @daniel: ok, thank you! (I'm getting away for now)

Comment: Very nice! Our prime-free gaps are identical for both intervals.

Comment: Legendre's conjecture assuming Andrica's conjecture:  $$\left(\{ p\in \textbf{P}: \sqrt{p_{n}}\}\cup \{n\in \textbf{N}^{+}\}\right)^{2}$$  Just throwing this out to see if it sticks.

Comment: Added a link from: http://mathoverflow.net/a/101133/16888

Comment: @GottfriedHelms, may be of interest. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/269405/973